# Why can't I calculate CostFunction J

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

This is my implementation of `CostFunctionJ`:

```
    function J = CostFunctionJ(X,y,theta)

    m = size(X,1);
    predictions = X*theta;
    sqrErrors =(predictions - y).^2;

    J = 1/(2*m)* sum(sqrErrors);
```

But when I try to enter the command in MATLAB as:

```
>> X = [1 1; 1 2; 1 3];
>> y = [1; 2; 3];
>> theta = [0,1];
>> J = CostFunctionJ(X,y,theta)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in CostFunctionJ (line 4)
predictions = X*theta;
```

Comment: You havent shown what `theta` or `X` are, but the problem is that they are not of compatible size for matrix multiplication. Do you want a matrix multiplication or are you looking for elementwise multiplication (`.*`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the error is because `x` is of dimension `3x2` and `theta` of dimension `1x2`, so you can't do `X*theta`.

I suspect you want:

```
theta = [0;1]; % note the ; instead of ,
% theta is now of dimension 2x1
% X*theta is now a legit operation
```

which would result in:

```
>> predictions = X*theta
predictions =

   1
   2
   3
```

Comment: Oh yeah that was the  mistake on my part instead of a comma , there should have been a semi colon(;). Thanks for the help.